# Why is win32api.GetAsyncKeyState not a global hotkey?

Tags: python, winapi, hotkeys

I'm trying to make a bot that automatically moves the mouse to a specific location. Only problem now is that the function was global, but now isn't anymore for some reason.

```
import mouse  
import configparser   
import win32api


hexstring = config.get("keypress", "keypress")
an_int = int(hexstring, 16) 

if win32api.GetAsyncKeyState(an_int)  < 0:
   mouse._os_mouse.move_relative(int(xcoord), int(ycoord))
```

Comment: What do you mean by "global"? + You don't have import for win32api and the check itself is done only once

Comment: I forgot to add the import, sorry. Edited it now. By global I mean the button press also working when you don't have the program on top. Thanks

Comment: I don't know what you mean. [GetAsyncKeyState](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getasynckeystate) is a procedure whose behavior is consistent.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found the error. I just needed to open the application as an administrator.